# Wordpress - Pop Up Page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, lightbox

Is there a easy way that I can set a plugin or `rel` tag to pop up another Wordpress local page within a lightbox situation.  I have googled but they are for posts etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes .. There is a plugin in WP called thickbox. You can add a lightbox, customize your lightbox, and also set a `rel` tag using it .

Comment: I have tried the above but I cannot seen to get it to load an html page

Comment: How come..I use it in one of my projects. How are u using it?